# Dynamically Derive Label Name in Loop?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

On a Visual Web Part pageLoad event (c#) I am calling a REST API which returns results in XML. I want to dynamically set labels in a table depending on the number of results returned. As the XML is parsed node 1 will set labels 1, node 2 labels 2 etc.

In the example code below I want to set the value of `Label1_1.Text` on iteration 1, `Label2_1.Text` on iteration 2, `Label3_1.Text` on iteration 3 and so on.

How can this be achieved?

```
foreach (XmlNode elem in nodes)
{
    string childOne     = elem["contact1"].InnerText.ToString();
    string childTwo     = elem["contact2"].InnerText.ToString();
    string childThree   = elem["contact3"].InnerText.ToString();
    string childFour    = elem["contact4"].InnerText.ToString();

    // I want Label1 to effectively be Labelx (x being the iteration)
    // so it is dynamic based on the number of iterations in the loop
    Label1_1.Text = childOne;
    Label1_2.Text = childTwo;
    Label1_3.Text = childThree;
    Label1_4.Text = childFour;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the FindControl method on the containing control if you already have all of the labels as controls within the container.

```
Label toUpdate = (Label)myTable.FindControl("Label1_1");
toUpdate.Text = childOne;
```

If the label controls don't already exist you will need to create and add them dynamically (in which case the Id would be need to be unique).